# Cache in proxy server

Tags: java, proxy, server

Hi I'm currently creating a proxy server and I need to implement a cache within the proxy server.

The cache is a hashmap with the URL being the key and the byte array of the URL will be the value.

Currently I am running into a problem when I am trying to write the byte array into the output stream of the client.

```
try{
                        if(!myCache.containsKey(urladdr))
                        {
                            IOUtils.copy(serverInput,toClient);
                            byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(connection);
                            myCache.addToCache(urladdr, byteArray);
                        }
                        else{
                            toClient.write(myCache.getValue(urladdr));
                            System.out.println("got from cache");
                        }
                    }
```

So basically if the URL is not in the cache yet, I will load the page using IOUtils.copy and then add the url + byte array to my cache.

If the URL is in my cache, I will get the byte array of the URL from the hashmap and write to the client. That is where my programme gets stuck, it just doesn't load the byte array into the client output stream.

Is it maybe a problem due to not sending any headers?
Help appreciated thanks

Comment: You need to send HTTP headers to the client otherwise it won't understand what it has received.

Comment: @SteveSmith how would I let my client know to expect a byte array?

Comment: I think it's a lot more complicated than you realise.  This might give you a head start: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039